# Transparency in XNA-4 primitives

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, rendering, visual-studio

I'm using XNA 4 with Visual Studio 2010. I'm trying to create a simple 3D world with walls and doors in which the user to free to roam around.

A wall is just a rectangle which is currently being rendered with four vertices using triangle strips. But to create a door, I'd have to split it into three rectangles as shown in the figure.

[image]

Four quadrilaterals if I want to have the following door-style

[image]

It will become more complex to have multiple doors on the same wall or if I have windows.

**Is there any shorter way to handle this? I am looking for something that will just make the wall transparent wherever I want.**

I found a solution but facing a problem [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75896/renderstate-in-xna-4)

Comment: To help with your searching, the name of the general solution to this problem is "**Triangulation**" - ie: taking an outline (and possibly additional outlines for holes) and converting that into a collection of triangles that can be used for rendering.

Comment: (It's worth pointing out that the solution you have linked - using a texture with the desired areas cut-out using alpha-testing - will also work. But it's a very different solution, and has a different set of tradeoffs for performance, visual quality and ease-of-use.)

Comment: I have concave polygons. According to [this](http://seabasealpha.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/drawing-and-triangulating-3d-polygons-in-xna/) link, triangulation is difficult for such cases. So, I guess the approach I mentioned (using quads) would be better for me.
Also, will triangulation work on windows (generally a hole in a polygon not connected to boundary)?

Comment: "Triangulation" usually implies working on concave shapes, given that convex shapes are trivial to triangulate. Generally you use a library to do the triangulation for you. A good library will handle polygons with holes correctly. Using quads is not really recommended - as they'll be converted to triangles anyway (quads are less efficient, less flexible). But using quads could be easier if you want a "quick and dirty" solution that doesn't depend on a third-party library.