# RenderState in XNA 4

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, graphics, xna3.1

I was going through [this](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Billboarding_renderstates.php) tutorial for having transparency which can be used to solve my problem [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75895/transparency-in-xna-4-primitives). The code is written in XNA 3 but I'm using XNA 4.

What is the alternative for the following code in XNA 4?

```
device.RenderState.AlphaTestEnable = true;
device.RenderState.AlphaFunction = CompareFunction.GreaterEqual;
device.RenderState.ReferenceAlpha = 200;
device.RenderState.DepthBufferWriteEnable = false;
```

I searched a lot but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: [Here is the blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/02/state-objects-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) that details the removal of the alpha test render state in XNA 4.0 (and the introduction of state objects). If alpha-testing is all you need, there is a built-in `AlphaTestEffect` that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can Alpha test in pixel shader by discarding the pixel if its alpha is below a certain level:

```
clip(color.a<0.1?-1,1);
```

or:

```
if(color.a<0.1)
 discard;
```

These two have the same effect which is discarding the pixel if its alpha is below 0.1. I am not sure what exactly is referencealpha in the renderstate but I am guessing it is an unnormalized alpha value, so 200 would be 200.0/255.0 in pixel shader.
You can turn off depth write by:

```
device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.DepthRead;
//device is your GraphicsDevice
```